# Visualizing density function - difference between displot() and plot()

Tags: python, statistics, seaborn, data-science

I visualize density function (PDF) using two plotting approaches: `displot()` and `plot()`. I don't understand why `displot()` doesn't produce normally distributed plot wheras `plot()` do this perfectly. Density plots should look alike but they don't. What's wrong with `displot()` here?

```
from scipy.stats import norm
import seaborn as sns 
import numpy as np

data_x= np.arange(-4, 4, 0.001)
norm_pdf = norm.pdf(data_x)
sns.displot(data = norm_pdf, x = data_x, kind='kde')
```

[image]

```
from scipy.stats import norm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data_x= np.arange(-4, 4, 0.001)
plt.plot(data_x, norm.pdf(data_x))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`displot` (or the underlying `kdeplot`) creates an approximation of a probability density function ([pdf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function)) to resemble the function that might have generated the given random data.  As input, you'll need random data. The function will mimic these data as a sum of Gaussian bell shapes (a ["kernel density estimation"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation) with a Gaussian kernel).

Here is an example using 8000 random points as input. You'll notice the curve resembles the normal pdf, but is also a bit "bumpier" (that's how randomness looks like).

```py
data_x = norm.rvs(size=8000)
sns.kdeplot(x=data_x)
```

[image: kdeplot of random normal data]

When you call `kdeplot` (or `displot(..., kind='kde')`) with both `data=` and `x=`, while `x=` isn't a columnname in a dataframe, `data=` gets ignored. So, you are using 8000 evenly distributed values between `-4` and `4`. The kde of such data looks like a flat line between -4 and 4. But as the kde supposes the underlying function locally resembles a Gaussian, the start and end are smoothed out.

```py
data_x = np.arange(-4, 4, 0.001)
sns.kdeplot(x=data_x)
```

[image: kdeplot of np.arange]

Comment: Ok, that expains a lot. So summing up: `displot` works fine only with random data generated from distribution (e.g. `norm.rvs`) or with dataset and dataframe column. This is how I think it works

Comment: Rephrasing "works fine for" to "is meant for" would be closer. `displot` doesn't draw pdfs, it draws kdes.